# Getting square images like gmail app

Tags: android, image

I want to show images with alphabets like `gmail app` as shown in the below figure.

[image]

Are all those images are images to be kept in drawable folder or they are drawn as `square shapes` and then letters are drawn to them? Below is what I tried so far to do dynamically. I got just a square shape. Can someone suggest the way to achieve like in gmail app?

```
GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
            gd.mutate();
            gd.setColor(getResources().getColor(gColors[i]));
button.setBackgroundDrawable(gd);
```

Comment: Those are probably ninepatch images.

Comment: @Anoo Take look at my answer. It will guide you for sure.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Update 2:**

I have fixed some of the bugs and released the code as an open source library at: https://github.com/amulyakhare/TextDrawable. It also include some other features that you might want to check out.

[image: sample screenshot]

---

**Old Answer:**

I recommend you to use the following class `CharacterDrawable` (just copy-paste this):

```
public class CharacterDrawable extends ColorDrawable {

    private final char character;
    private final Paint textPaint;
    private final Paint borderPaint;
    private static final int STROKE_WIDTH = 10;
    private static final float SHADE_FACTOR = 0.9f;

    public CharacterDrawable(char character, int color) {
        super(color);
        this.character = character;
        this.textPaint = new Paint();
        this.borderPaint = new Paint();

        // text paint settings
        textPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        textPaint.setFakeBoldText(true);
        textPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);

        // border paint settings
        borderPaint.setColor(getDarkerShade(color));
        borderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        borderPaint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
    }

    private int getDarkerShade(int color) {
        return Color.rgb((int)(SHADE_FACTOR * Color.red(color)),
                         (int)(SHADE_FACTOR * Color.green(color)),
                         (int)(SHADE_FACTOR * Color.blue(color)));
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas);

        // draw border
        canvas.drawRect(getBounds(), borderPaint);

        // draw text
        int width = canvas.getWidth();
        int height = canvas.getHeight();
        textPaint.setTextSize(height / 2);
        canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(character), width/2, height/2 - ((textPaint.descent() + textPaint.ascent()) / 2) , textPaint);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
        textPaint.setAlpha(alpha);
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
        textPaint.setColorFilter(cf);
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    }
}
```

Then using this is simple: `new CharacterDrawable('A', 0xFF805781);` by passing the character and the color value (example `Color.RED` or some other color in hex `0xFF805781`):

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
CharacterDrawable drawable = new CharacterDrawable('A', 0xFF805781);
imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

or based on your question:

```
CharacterDrawable drawable = new CharacterDrawable('A', 0xFF805781);    
button.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

The `drawable` will scale to fit the size of the `ImageView`. Result will be:

[image]

> **Update:** Updated code for adding a border which is of darker shade (automatically picks a dark shade based on the fill color).

1) Change the value of `STROKE_WIDTH` based on your needs for the border thikness.

2) Change the value of `SHADE_FACTOR` for border darkness. If `SHADE_FACTOR` is small (eg. `0.2f`), the border will be darker and vice versa.

*Note: You can easily vary the size and font of the character*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This seems to be it. But the picture in the question contains small border around it which is bit thick of the color that it contains, so any suggestions for it?

Comment: Is it? I cannot notice it in high resolution: http://lh4.ggpht.com/-3qBcOS-1als/UbH0H0O_LuI/AAAAAAAAAVY/dRl7bLlZN9g/s1600/Screenshot_2013-06-05-16-11-35.png? Can you give an example of it? It is probably easy to change..

Comment: In the image you have given, border line is somewhat more visible in the left side of that images. Like the first image in the listview contains more thick blue line as it contains blue and the next item contains purple and so on.

Comment: The character is not visible for some reason on the colored square. I don't understand why.

Comment: when??, is the alpha correct, should not be transparent.. you can read some documentation / samples about `Paint` and drawing on `Canvas`. It will really be helpful..

Comment: I did nothing, I just used the same code and used that class like this->  CharacterDrawable drawable = new CharacterDrawable('J', 0xFFa8bb29);
   imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);

Comment: You should set a size for the `ImageView`. If you leave it `WRAP_CONTENT` then the `drawable` will not know what size to show.

Comment: Tested with Gingerbread, the letter doesn't come out. Any solution?

Comment: Updated: In GIngerbread, draw(Canvas canvas) canvas width/height is the screen width/height instead of ImageView width/height.

Comment: @neobie I'm in Android API Level 4.1.2 and the letter doesn't come out. What's wrong?

Comment: @Mr.Hyde I haven't tested with 4.1.2 yet. For my gingerbread, I manually set the canvas size of 38.

Comment: @neobie I manually set the canvas size like this: int width = 96;;;; But it's not work!

Comment: @AmulyaKhare I'm in Android API Level 4.1.2 and the letter doesn't come out. What's wrong? I manually set the canvas size like this: int width = 96;;;; But it's not work!

Comment: Fixed some of the mentioned bugs and release the library at https://github.com/amulyakhare/TextDrawable

Comment: @AmulyaKhare Thanks for the awesome lib ! any easy trick possible for displaying multiple line (2lines) https://github.com/amulyakhare/TextDrawable/issues/20

Answer (score 2):

Simple thing is that you have use Linear Layout and set that background color and set TectView inside that root layout. Its Over.

You should use ColorCode Intesed of images that will good thing compare to use images in terms of loading on UI thread.

```
  <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/get_more"
            android:layout_width="70dp" // this root layout will set your square 
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:background="#654321" // set background color of square 
            android:orientation="horizontal" >


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:text="C"
                android:background="#ffffff" // Text Color , set as White
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tweak the code a little bit..., and it works everytime even with different screen sizes. The trick is to obtain the ImageView canvas size in pixels (which sometimes is density dependent on various devices)

```
package net.mypapit.android.ui;

import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.ColorFilter;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;


public class CharacterDrawable extends ColorDrawable {

    private final char character;
    private final Paint textPaint;
    private final Paint borderPaint;
    private static final int STROKE_WIDTH = 10;
    private static final float SHADE_FACTOR = 0.9f;
    private int mwidth, mheight;

    public CharacterDrawable(char character, int color, int width, int height) {
        super(color);
        this.character = character;
        this.textPaint = new Paint();
        this.borderPaint = new Paint();
        this.mwidth = width;
        this.mheight = height;

        // text paint settings 
        textPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        textPaint.setFakeBoldText(true);
        textPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);

        // border paint settings 
        borderPaint.setColor(getDarkerShade(color));
        borderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        borderPaint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
    } 

    private int getDarkerShade(int color) {
        return Color.rgb((int)(SHADE_FACTOR * Color.red(color)),
                         (int)(SHADE_FACTOR * Color.green(color)),
                         (int)(SHADE_FACTOR * Color.blue(color)));
    } 

    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas);

        // draw border 
        canvas.drawRect(getBounds(), borderPaint);

        // draw text 
        int width = this.mwidth;
        int height = this.mheight;
        textPaint.setTextSize(height / 2);
        canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(character), width/2, height/2 - ((textPaint.descent() + textPaint.ascent()) / 2) , textPaint);
    } 

    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
        textPaint.setAlpha(alpha);
    } 

    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
        textPaint.setColorFilter(cf);
    } 

    public int getOpacity() { 
        return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    } 
}
```

Then, refer back to the original Amulya Khare answer:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
CharacterDrawable drawable = new CharacterDrawable('A', 0xFF805781,imageView.getWidth(),imageView.getHeight());
imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

It should work on different screen density by now =)

Comment: I need this to be circular please